# White Screen Activity After Add Button XML : Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

When I add a button and running the application, it displays a white screen and no activity  appears.

This problem is only for the button: when I remove the button and run the application again, activity will be displayed without any problems.

My XML code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity2"
android:background="@color/pink">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Well with those constraints the button will take up the entire screen-  its forced to the entire parent.  So yeah, anything else could be forced to render underneath that.

Comment: I tried your code, it is showing button in center. Please explain more.

Comment: I have tried your code and it is showing correctly. Please explain more about this.